# MacOS/Debian10 dual boot- how to delete unknown EFI partition?

Tags: macos, startup, catalina, unix, dual-boot

I have a macbook air dual booting macOS Catalina and Debian10 buster. I hold the option key at startup to choose the system I want. In the boot manager there's this efi partition (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAvHb.jpg) that I would like to delete, because it starts nothing but grub bash minimal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLvC4.jpg), but I have not been able to identify this partition neither from macOS 'diskutils' nor from Debian 'fdisk'.

How could I delete this partition?
[image: boot loader]

[image: output of "?" efi entry]

**EDIT:**

Command `diskutil list disk0` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         305.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         205.5 GB   disk0s3
   4:                        EFI NO NAME                 536.9 MB   disk0s4
```

Comment: Usually this happens when you have more than one EFI partition. Can you post the output from the linux commands `lsblk`, `mount | grep sda` and `/usr/sbin/gdisk -l /dev/sda`? You may have to be the root user to enter the command  `/usr/sbin/gdisk -l /dev/sda`. Or, post the output from the macOS command `diskutil list`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'll edit my question and post the output you've asked. I've found out that it's not a "partition", but it's something in configuration files or something like this in the efi partition of Debian. It contains 3 folders: APPLE, boot and Debian.

Comment: I mean, the folders (APPLE, boot and Debian) are in the disk0s4 partition.

Answer (score 2):

You have two EFI partitions. Only one has the correct boot files. The other does not. You can try renaming a folder in the first EFI partition and see if this solves your problem. The commands are given below.

```
sudo disktuil mount disk0s1
mv /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT /Volumes/EFI/EFI/NOBOOT
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

If this does not solve your problem, then undo the above commands and try then other EFI partition. The commands are given below.

```
sudo disktuil mount disk0s1
mv /Volumes/EFI/EFI/NOBOOT /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT
diskutil unmount disk0s1
sudo disktuil mount disk0s4
mv /Volumes/NO\ NAME/EFI/BOOT /Volumes/NO\ NAME/EFI/NOBOOT
diskutil unmount disk0s4
```

If this fixed your problem, then you should consider changing the label to something better than `EFI Boot`. And/or add an icon.

Answer (score 0):

Open Disk Utility in the Application/Utilities folder and select the Volume of interest. Then click on the Partition tab at the top. This will display all partitions on the selected Volume.

Comment: It doesn`t appear in disk utility. I think this may be something in a config file in debian's partition.